# WCF ChannelFactory IDuplexSessionChannel

Tags: wcf, channel, channelfactory

I am using a `ChannelFactory` to communicate with external services by sending raw soap requests. I have a NetTcp endpoint that uses the `IDuplexSessionChannel`. I tried creating a `IRequestChannel/IRequestSessionChannel` using `binding.BuildChannelFactory<T>()`, but that did not work (threw exception). From what I read online, duplex channels can be used like request channels, where you call a service method and get an immediate response. I want to know if the below code accomplishes that. I searched everywhere to see an example of `ChannelFactory` and `IDuplexSessionChannel`, but could not find anything. Lastly, if this were an IDuplexChannel instead of an IDuplexSessionChannel, would the implementation be any different since one is sessionful and the other isn't?

```
IChannelFactory factory;
IChannel        channel;

Binding         binding = GetBindingFromConfig( bindingName );
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress( endpointAddress );

if( binding.CanBuildChannelFactory<IDuplexSessionChannel>() )
{
    factory = binding.BuildChannelFactory<IDuplexSessionChannel>();
    factory.Open();
    channel = ( (IChannelFactory<IDuplexSessionChannel>)factory ).CreateChannel( address );
    channel.Open();

    ( (IDuplexSessionChannel)channel ).Send( requestMessage );
    ( (IDuplexSessionChannel)channel ).TryReceive( Timespan.MaxValue, out responseMessage );
}
```

Here is my configuration file:

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding
        name="xyz"
        closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
        sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        transactionFlow="false"
        transferMode="Buffered"
        transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        listenBacklog="10"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxBufferSize="10485760"
        maxConnections="10"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">

        <readerQuotas
            maxDepth="32"
            maxStringContentLength="8192"
            maxArrayLength="10485760"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096"
            maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

        <reliableSession
            ordered="true"
            inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />

        <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

Comment: you say it threw an exception - what did it throw and where?

Comment: Throws at binding.BuildChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(). ArgumentException: The specified channel type System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel is not supported by this channel manager. Parameter name: TChannel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix the issue, here it is:

```
ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> factory;
IRequestChannel                 channel;

Binding         binding = GetBindingFromConfig( bindingName );
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress( endpointAddress );

factory = new ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>( binding, address );

// Since this endpoint uses sessions, we have to allow sessions to prevent an exception.
factory.Endpoint.Contract.SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed;

factory.Open();
channel = factory.CreateChannel( address );
channel.Open();

responseMessage = channel.Request( requestMessage );
```

Credits: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/06/25/changing-the-channelfactory-contract.aspx